# JpaRepository native query not detecting parameters

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to write a native query in my SpringBoot application to get the closest location to any given coordinate. Following is the JpaRepository for the same:

```
@Repository
public interface OfferRepository extends JpaRepository<Offer, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT *, MIN(6371000 * acos( cos( radians(:latitude) ) * cos( radians( dest.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( dest.longitude ) - radians(:longitude) ) + sin( radians(:latitude) ) * sin( radians( dest.latitude ) ))) as  distance FROM offer dest GROUP BY dest.id having MIN(distance)",
            nativeQuery = true)
    Tuple getClosestOffer(double latitude, double longitude);
}
```

The problem I am facing it that the passed latitude and longitude are not getting set in the query string. Instead they are replaced with question marks as seen below:

```
SELECT *, MIN(6371000 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( dest.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( dest.longitude ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( dest.latitude ) ))) as  distance FROM offer dest GROUP BY dest.id having MIN(distance)
```

I even tried with numbered parameters, but with same result. What am I doing wrong here? How to solve this?

Comment: Can you please share what result/error is shown by spring when you call that query? Because it is possible that the parameters not have been set yet by hibernate when you log the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *Named Parameters* using the *@Param* annotation

```
public interface OfferRepository extends JpaRepository<Offer, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT *, MIN(6371000 * acos( cos( radians(:latitude) ) * cos( radians( dest.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( dest.longitude ) - radians(:longitude) ) + sin( radians(:latitude) ) * sin( radians( dest.latitude ) ))) as  distance FROM offer dest GROUP BY dest.id having MIN(distance)",
            nativeQuery = true)
    Tuple getClosestOffer(@Param("latitude") double latitude, @Param("longitude") double longitude);
}
```

or use *Indexed Parameters: ?1 ?2* in you jpql

```
public interface OfferRepository extends JpaRepository<Offer, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT *, MIN(6371000 * acos( cos( radians(?1) ) * cos( radians( dest.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( dest.longitude ) - radians(?2) ) + sin( radians(?1) ) * sin( radians( dest.latitude ) ))) as  distance FROM offer dest GROUP BY dest.id having MIN(distance)",
            nativeQuery = true)
    Tuple getClosestOffer(double latitude, double longitude);
}
```

if you want to show the resolved parameters in your logging just set the logging level of *org.hibernate.type* to *trace*

*application.properties :*

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace
```

Comment: @Harikrishnan _Still showing same query_ in logging (console)? Yes, that is how hibernate translates your query, but what about the result in your tuple?

Comment: @Harikrishnan and does the query return a unique result? Otherwise, use _Set<Tuple>_